# How to activate opened excel in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA code that I used to open an excel and do an automatic process. My code is

```
Dim strPath As String
Dim intChoice As Integer
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
If intChoice <> 0 Then
strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)

Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    strPath
```

The process is done here, and this process is navigating between 2 excels, the one that contains the Macro and the one that contains the data. Let's say Excel A and Excel B.
I do the automation in Excel B based on a button in Excel A and then I cut the data from B and add it to A.
Now my problem is that the excels which contains the data are different in names, so I reach to this point in the code:

```
Windows("EPS.xlsx"). _
    Activate
```

Where I want this "EPS.xlsx" to be replaced by file which was already opened by strPath in the code I wrote in the beginning of this question.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think about *activating* or *selecting* any workbooks.  All you want to do is reference the correct workbook.

Rather than use `Workbooks.Open Filename:= strPath` which will just open the file, you want to open the file and store a reference to it in a variable.  You can then use that variable whenever you want to do something with the workbook.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrkBk1 As Workbook
    Dim wrkBk2 As Workbook

    Set wrkBk1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath)
    Set wrkBk2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strOtherPath)

    wrkBk1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = 5
    wrkBk2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = wrkBk1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

    wrkBk1.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").NumberFormat = "@"
    wrkBk2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5").Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

End Sub
```

Your code would look something like:

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim strPath As String
    Dim intChoice As Integer

    Dim wrkBk As Workbook

    intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
    If intChoice <> 0 Then
        strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
        msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)

        Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath)
        MsgBox wrkBk.Name & " has been opened.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped me, it was what I was missing. Thank you again

Comment: Whoop.... and I go sailing past the 10k rep mark.  Really shouldn't gamify these forums. :)